# Windows: ImportError: No module named Image

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to create a function which reads pptx files. The only module I found is `python-pptx`. But unfortunately, it raises errors.

There were some problems with installing `Pillow` when I did: `pip install python-pptx` so I installed it `easy_install Pillow` which seems to be working. Then I installed `python-pptx`. The problem is that when I execute the function it still raises error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Milano/Desktop/Projekty/FS Dropbox/Dropbox/word_counter.py", line 38, in <module>
    print get_pptx_word_count('pptx.pptx')
  File "C:/Users/Milano/Desktop/Projekty/FS Dropbox/Dropbox/word_counter.py", line 15, in get_pptx_word_count
    from pptx import Presentation
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sfl_venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pptx.api import Presentation  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sfl_venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\api.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .package import Package
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sfl_venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\package.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .parts.image import Image, ImagePart
  File "C:\Users\Milano\Desktop\Projekty\venvs\sfl_venv\lib\site-packages\pptx\parts\image.py", line 13, in <module>
    import Image as PIL_Image
ImportError: No module named Image
```

What should I do? I'm on `virtualenv`. Tried to uninstall Pillow and install PIL but it didn't find anything.

Comment: Download Pillow from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and Use `from PIL import Image` instead of `import Image`.

Answer (score 0):

pillow moves all the PIL modules to the `PIL` package. You will need to modify the import to `PIL.Image`.